# Is there an OSM Mapnik Gray Basemap in English

Tags: arcgis-desktop, openstreetmap, labeling, mapnik, basemap

I have found a basemap, the OSM (Mapnik SW) map, that I would like to incorporate into a project in ArcMap. It has a great blend of gray scale methods to denote urban areas, terrain, and water features, while the gray scale leaves room for thematic layers.

The link to the map is here:

http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=19285b9249484a0585aa95e423b605da

My issue is that I need the map labels to be in English throughout the map. Unfortunately when I zoom into a non-English speaking region, like Taiwan, the basemap displays labels in Taiwanese.

Does anyone know of a similar basemap with English labels, preferably OSM Mapnik SW styled or a way to change these labels to English?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Light-all" layer from Carto might be what you are looking for.

Go to:

http://cartodb-basemaps-c.global.ssl.fastly.net

And in the bottom right corner, select the "light_all" layer.

Answer (score 2):

[stamen toner](http://maps.stamen.com/toner/) is black/white with all labels in English.